# Number of monotonic paths in a rectangular grid avoiding certain points

Tags: combinatorics

In a rectangular grid of size $m \times n$, the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ (without backtracking) is ${m+n \choose {n}} = \frac{(m+n)!}{(m!*n!)}$.

Now if there are certain points in the grid which we want to avoid, how can we calculate the number of paths avoiding those points?
Thanks in advance.

Note: The number of forbidden points could go up to $200$ in a $100000 * 100000$ grid.

Comment: to count the paths that avoid a particular point $P$, just subtract the number of paths that go through $P$ from your answer above. The paths that go through $P$ are easily counted using the same technique as the one you used. For more points to avoid, one could attempt Inclusion/Exclusion, but this could rapidly get out of hand.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your attention. In my problem I've got $200$ points to avoid in a $100000 * 100000$ grid, so the inclusion/exclusion would come to $2 ^ {200}$ ? Please point out if I got it wrong.

Comment: As I mentioned, Inclusion/exclusion rapidly becomes unfeasible, and at $200$ it is truly hopeless. I do not have a feasible suggestion for a problem that large.

Comment: @SCaffrey Did you solve the problem ? If yes, please post your answer.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar Hi I didn't solve this problem. I got this idea from a programming contest problem. The problem here is much more complex than in the contest. We used [Lindström–Gessel–Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma) in the contest actually. If you are able to read Chinese, I'd be glad to share the problem and the solution with you.

Comment: @SCaffrey Sorry, I don't know Chinese. Btw, I got a very similar type of problem in [codeforces](http://codeforces.com/contest/560/problem/E) and editorial also has the solution idea though I didn't look at the editorial yet.

Comment: @SCaffrey Ping me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/khairulbasar/) if you are available and have time to discuss about this in detail. :)

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I thought I sent you an invitation on linkedin. But to be honest, the problem here has little association with the contest problem. I'll do some translation later.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<s<m$ and $0<t<n$ then the number of ways going through point $(s,t)$ is

$\binom{s+t}{s}\cdot \binom{(m-s)+(n-t)}{m-s}$.

If you avoid point (s,t) you have to substract this number from $\binom{n+m}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to deal with 200 points? I mean, I guess I can't just simply add the numbers together when there are multiple points to avoid.

Comment: I think only an approximation can be made. Do the avoiding points are placed in a specific pattern ?

Comment: The only pattern I found is that for each point p(x, y), we've got $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq m$.

Comment: I really don´t see how this problem could be managed, sorry.